# Git ChangeLog for Sub-modules

Tags: git, changelog

Looking for help to get the git change log  since last successful build(including sub-modules) in Jenkins.The change log should contain only the merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a groovy script used your Jenkins build (as in "[How to get commits information on Jenkins using Groovy since last successful build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461301/6309)") in order to get the changet set for all builds since the last successful one.

As shown in "[How to get list of changed files since last build in Jenkins/Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862273/6309)", you can also script it (run from *outside* any Jenkins build), in order to get that same list.

Comment: Thanks.I am seeing below error while executing the script:-[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars as a build wrap: null
11:27:46 Finished: FAILURE